# SQL Select Using Different Parameters from the Same Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, subquery

Concept is simple: Get a field from table1 based on a certain id and a field from table2 based on a different id from table1 that represents the highest the record with the highest value. All one query, two tables.

I have tried, joins, sub-queries, joins AND sub-queries and a mixture of everything to no avail. If anyone is able to accomplish this they will have my deepest respect since I have been trying this for two days now. Here are the steps in pseudo-code:

1. tables: table1 (field1 and field3) and table2 (field2)
2. SELECT from table1 field1 and from table2 field2
3. Get field1 based on table1.id
4. Get field2 from table2 based on table1.id which has the highest
   value in field3

Things to know: table2 has a foreign key linking to table 1. I use the information in table1 differently to create reviews and their comments which are basically the same thing and contain the same type of data but used differently. I keep them apart by knowing who is the parent (review) and who is the child (comment). I am trying to get the review data and its description based on which comment has the most views, for example.

Sample query:

```
SELECT reviews.title, descriptions.description
FROM reviews, descriptions
WHERE reviews.id = 1
AND descriptions.review_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM reviews
    WHERE views = (
        SELECT MAX(views)
        FROM reviews
        WHERE parent = 1
        -- Parent is the same id used above to select the review
    )
);
```

I get empty set results in most queries I have tried other queries just give me repeated data in the views field.
I know some of you might argue that I should make a different table for my comments but I think this way saves a lot of database space and I have taken this as a challenge. Thank you all in advance.

**NOTE: PLEASE READ THE QUESTION** - without reading it entirely it will be difficult to understand.

As requested:

```
table: reviews
id |   title   | views |
2    'My Title'    5
1    'Other Title' 1
3    'Third Title' 3

table: description
id |     description      | review_id |
1     'Good description'       2
2     'Great description'      1
3     'Bad description'        3
```

Result should be: 'Good description' is selected because it the description linking to the review with the most views. The title is selected based on the passed in.

```
title     |  description     |
'Other Title' 'Good description'
```

Comment: The title of your post should reflect the problem

Comment: Well, it seem impossible to me...

Comment: could you clarify slightly - I think I know what you want jusging by your query - can you do 3 dummy rows from table 1 3 dummy rows from table 2 and then what you would expect out of the query at the end - makes life easier and saves me writing some SQL that isnt what you want!

Comment: Check my edit with sample tables @Graham Ritchie.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this works in SqlServer not sure about MySQL, but perhaps it will help you get on the right track.

```
Select Top 1 Parent.Title, Descriptions.Description
From Reviews Parent
    inner join Reviews Child
        on Parent.Id = Child.Parent
    inner join Descriptions
        on Child.Id = Descriptions.review_id
Where Parent.Id = 1
Order By Child.[Views] desc
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89a76/1

Psuedo Code without Table Names as Requested

> ```
> Select Take the Top 1 Parent.Title, Descriptions.Description
> From Table1 (The Parent)
>   inner join Table1 Back onto itself (The Child)
>       linking The parents Id to the Child's Parent
>   inner join Table2 onto the Child
>       Linking Child's Id to the Descriptions' review_id
> Where the parents Id is 1 (or the Passed in value)
> Order By The number of views the child had desc
> ```

Comment: You are not getting the description based on the review with the most views.

Comment: Ok I updated my code to return the top 1 with the most views.

Comment: Brandon Johnson please, read the question entirely that is not even remotely close to what I wish to do. I do appreciate your help!

Comment: Ok so let me see if I understand. You want the Review and it's Description where it has the child that has the most views. Is that correct?

Comment: I want data for this review say review1 based on this id. Then, I also want the description for the review that has the most views but also has review1 id as a parent. Get it?

Comment: Ok this might help. Could you please add Parent to your sample tables.    That may help clairify.

Comment: Ok I may have figured it out. Is that closer to what you are looking for?

Comment: Child is an alias of the Request table. I joined the Request Table to itself so I had to give it an alias. In The code `inner join Reviews Child` Child is the alias in other words Child is the new temporary name for Reviews.

Comment: Except for the title everything else is wrong in the result. I get 0 views and the description is also wrong since it should be based on the most views. @Brandon Johnson

Comment: Ok I ported my solution over to fiddle and added a link in the answer. It appears to me to be working correctly. It currently returns Other Title, Good Description, which has 5 views.  I'm not sure why you are getting 0 views.

Comment: Maybe because of the way I set it up in MySQL? Do you have some knowledge how this could be done in MySQL?

Comment: Sorry. I haven't really ever used MySQL perhaps there is a converter somewhere online.

Comment: Brandon you're the best man, I don't think it's really about anyone giving out the exact solution but about trying their best and you have certainly outdone it. I will vote up your answer and will try to convert it now. For the record can you do a pseudo-code where you do the above without using any exact tables?

Comment: No problem. Glad I could sort of help.  I added some Psuedoish code up above. Thank you for your patience. For a while I was really thinking this could be the "Impossible Query".

Comment: Ha ha, is still is for me. Thanks a lot for your help.